# TP- Link Not working on dual boot

Tags: linux, windows, wireless-networking, router, wifi-driver

Model : TL-WN725N

I have been using windows for a long time now. I haven't faces any issues with the tp-link adapter.

Today i dual booted windows and pop os(linux). I installed the drivers on the linux and the adapter just works fine. I can connect to networks and all. But the issues came as soon as i boots between the two operating systems.

If i am on windows right now and when i reboot back to windows, the tp-link adapter can automatically detect(lights up ) and starts working, connects to netwoks. But whenever i tries to reboot to linux, it is not detecting or connecting to any networks. Everytime i have to manually unplug the tp-link adapter and plug it again while i am on linux. Then it will work without any issues. But like i said, If i boot to windows again and boots backs to linux. problem starts.

I want the adapter to work automatically without any hassle. Can anyone help with what is going on here?

Comment: I think the USB card remembers its connection and will require disconnect and re-connect to make it work. This is the way with my own USB Internet Stick as well.

Comment: @John Oh that is really annoying. So you haven't find any solutions yet?

Comment: USB card memory keeps the current configuration and I have not found any way around it.  I have been using these devices for a number of years.

Comment: One way, an alternative - not an answer, and the way I do things is to make non-dominate machines Virtual Guest machines with the dominant machine as Host. Then the USB card can service both machines at the same time.

Comment: @John You mean instead of dual boot, install one os on virtual machine.?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. In a number of cases, virtual machines are easier than dual boot.

Comment: @John But my system is not so capable of doing that. anyways thank you.

Comment: I understand and respect that. So you will likely have to live with shutting down, remove USB, start up, insert USB. The cards I know work that way.

Comment: @John Ok bud. <3